# Focus style for TextInput in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

In React Native, how do you change the style of a `textInput` when it gets focus? Say I have something like

```
class MyInput extends Component {
    render () {
        return <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />;
    }
};

const stylesObj = {
    textInput: {
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 15,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        color: 'black',
    }
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create(stylesObj);
```

And I want to change the background color on focus to `green`.

[This documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#content) leads me to believe that the solution is something like

```
class MyInput extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {hasFocus: false};
    }

    render () {
        return (<TextInput
            style={this.state.hasFocus ? styles.focusedTextInput : styles.textInput}
            onFocus={this.setFocus.bind(this, true)}
            onBlur={this.setFocus.bind(this, false)}
        />);
    }

    setFocus (hasFocus) {
        this.setState({hasFocus});
    }
};

const stylesObj = {
    textInput: {
        height: 50,
        fontSize: 15,
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        color: 'black',
    }
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...stylesObj,
    focusedTextInput: {
        ...stylesObj,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    }
});
```

Ignoring potential mistakes in the styles structuring, would this be considered correct way to handle it? It seems very verbose to me.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing in the onFocus and onBlur events to set and unset styles when focused and blurred:

```
  onFocus() {
    this.setState({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    })
  },

  onBlur() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: '#ededed'
    })
  },
```

And then, in the TextInput do this:

```
<TextInput 
    onBlur={ () => this.onBlur() }
    onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }
    style={{ height:60, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, color: this.state.color }}  />
```

I've set up a full working project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/hYrKmQ). I hope this helps!

https://rnplay.org/apps/hYrKmQ

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
        backgroundColor: '#ededed',
      color: 'white'
    }
  },

  onFocus() {
        this.setState({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    })
  },

  onBlur() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: '#ededed'
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput 
        onBlur={ () => this.onBlur() }
        onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }
        style={{ height:60, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, color: this.state.color }}  />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:60
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. It's essentially the same process, which seems to be *the way* to these things.

Comment: you can also (and you should) write onBlur={ this.onBlur } to prevent that a new anonymous function is created every time render() is called

Comment: onBlur={ this.onBlur.bind(this) } to bind the component otherwise "this" might not be accessible inside the method call

Comment: what if you have more than one <TextInput> in the View and want to only style the current focused one?

Comment: This solution seems a temporary solution, do tell what will happen in case of multiple TextInput in one screen and we want to set different styles for focused and non focused

Comment: how we can have it in function component?

Answer (score 16):

The best way to control the style when the element is focused / blurred is to create your own TextInput wrapper

```
export const MyAppTextInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Note that `{...props}` will pass in any property you already set or available for TextInput.

Then extend the above component by adding state to apply styles when focus / blur

```
export const MyAppTextInput = (props) => {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={[props.style, isFocused && {borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'blue'}]}
      onBlur={() => setIsFocused(false)}
      onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
    />
  );
};
```

And remember when you use the component to bind the value like in the example (see `value={passwordText}`); otherwise the value will disappear on blur as a new render commences after the state change.

```
<MyAppTextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={passwordText}
          textContentType="password"
          autoCompleteType="off"
          secureTextEntry
          onChangeText={text => {
            setPasswordText(text);
          }}
        />
```

You can of course avoid creating a wrapper but if you have more than one input it will create a mess in your input(s) parent components as you will have to add repeating logic.

Answer (score 8):

Use refs, DirectManipulation and setNativeProps for more performance: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.

```
class MyInput extends Component {
  focusedInput = () => { 
    this.textInput.setNativeProps({
      style: { backgroundColor: 'green' }
    }) 
  }

  blurredInput = () => { 
    this.textInput.setNativeProps({
      style: { backgroundColor: 'yellow' }
    }) 
  }

  render () {
      return <TextInput 
                ref={c => { this.textInput = c}} 
                style={styles.textInput}
                onFocus={this.focusedInput}
                onBlur={this.blurredInput} />
  }
```

}

const stylesObj = {
      textInput: {
          height: 50,
          fontSize: 15,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          color: 'black',
      }
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create(stylesObj)

This updates the TextInput component directly without re-rendering the component hierarchy.

Comment: Will this only work for one TextInput in/on a Component?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson you could implement this for any number of inputs - just assign a different ref to each one.  You could then pass the ref name to your focusedInput function, and call this[refName].setNativeProps from there

Answer (score 5):

You can create a state to keep track of the input-state and use that state to toggle the style. Here is a simple example

```
const App = () => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <TextInput style={{ color: isActive ? 'black' : 'grey' }} onFocus={() => setActive(true)} onBlur={() => setActive(false)}/>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For that propose I design this simple logic in functional component (it works the same in class components with the pertinents changes), it can be apply to several `<textinputs/>`. Below I leave an example:

```
// state
     const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState({
       name: false,
       email: false,
       phone: false,
     })
// handlers
     const handleInputFocus = (textinput) => {
       setIsFocused({
         [textinput]: true
       })
     }
     const handleInputBlur = (textinput) => {
       setIsFocused({
         [textinput]: false
       })
     }
// JSX

     <View style={styles.form} >
        <TextInput
          style={isFocused.name ? [styles.inputs, { borderColor: 'blue' }] : styles.inputs}
          placeholder='Name'
          placeholderTextColor={darkColors.text}
          textContentType='name'
          keyboardType='default'
          onFocus={() => handleInputFocus('name')}
          onBlur={() => handleInputBlur('name')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={isFocused.email ? [styles.inputs, { borderColor: 'blue' }] : styles.inputs}
          placeholder='Email'
          placeholderTextColor={darkColors.text}
          textContentType='emailAddress'
          keyboardType='email-address'
          onFocus={() => handleInputFocus('email')}
          onBlur={() => handleInputBlur('email')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={isFocused.phone ? [styles.inputs, { borderColor: 'blue' }] : styles.inputs}
          placeholder='Phone'
          placeholderTextColor={darkColors.text}
          keyboardType='phone-pad'
          onFocus={() => handleInputFocus('phone')}
          onBlur={() => handleInputBlur('phone')}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nader Dabit´s pointed me to do something similar -- using the state for styles -- but I think it can be done in a cleaner way if you created separate styles for the focused and unfocused style and pass only the style ID as follows:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { style: styles.textinput_unfocused }
}
onFocus() {
  this.setState({ style: styles.textinput_focused })
}
onBlur() {
  this.setState({ style: styles.textinput_unfocused })
}
```

in render -- referencing by styleID in `this.state.style`, note how the different styles are passed as an Array:

```
<TextInput 
  onBlur={ () => this.onBlur() }
  onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }
  style={ [styles.textinput, this.state.style] }  />
```

+ your stylesheet à la carte:

```
textinput_focused: {
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  color: 'white'
}
textinput_unfocused: {
  backgroundColor: 'green'
}
```

Comment: What if I have 2 TextInputs while one is focused but the other is not? `style={ [styles.textinput, this.state.style] }` seems to apply to all TextInputs.

Comment: no, the dynamic part is still set by `this.setState`, thus applies only to the textfield on which the event was triggered. the example given is just to have some overridable base styles that are left unchanged, which should have been a comment mayhems .

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys I kinda used everyones idea :p

@Felix gave me an idea that might be perhaps even cleaner. (I would have loved to not have included state though on this static component, just to change styling... But I am to new to this to figure that out.

here was my solution:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class TxtInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      style: {},
    };
  }

  onFocus = () => {
    const state = { ...this.state };
    state.style = {
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderColor: '#e74712',
    };

    this.setState(state);
  }

  onBlur = () => {
    console.log('on ONBLUR')
    const state = { ...this.state };
    state.style = {};

    this.setState(state);
  }

  render = () => <TextInput style={[styles.input, this.state.style]} onFocus={() => this.onFocus()} onBlur={() => this.onBlur()} />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontFamily: 'MuseoSans 700 Italic',
    fontSize: 22,
    borderRadius: 34,
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    borderWidth: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    width: '25%',
 },
});

export default TxtInput;
```

I added the style into an array, have all the actual input styling done on the first property of the array and the second one the nit picking of the focus and blue.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextInput
 style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', height: 40, width: 100, alignItems: 'center' 
   }} 
 theme={{ colors: { placeholder: 'white', text: 'white', primary: 'white', 
  underlineColor: 'transparent', background: '#003489' } }}
   />
```

Comment: Can you explain what 'theme' is doing, and how it changes the input styles on focus and blur?

Answer (score 0):

set initial value in function component

`const [warnColor, setWrnColor] = useState("grey");`

set this in text input

`style={[styles.brdColor, { borderColor: warnColor }]}`

set this in stylesheet

```
 brdColor: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: "grey",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    marginTop: heightToDp("2%"),
    width: "100%",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `TextInput` border color on focus, by using react hooks `useState` and `useCallback`.

```
const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
const handleFocus = useCallback(() => {
  setIsFocused(!isFocused);
}, [isFocused]);
let bcOnFocus = {
  borderColor: isFocused ? '#000000' : '#cccccc',
};

<ScrollView>
  <View>
    <TextInput
          placeholder="Text Field"
          style={bcOnFocus}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
    />
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```