# Change underlineColorAndroid on Focus for TextInput in react-native

Tags: react-native

Similar to [Focus style for TextInput in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native), I am trying to change the property underlineColorAndroid for the textInput.

I am using React-Native 0.28.0

OnFocus, the attribute doesn't change. How do I change the underline to a different color onFocus?

My sample code is below:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

class RNPlayground extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hasFocus: false
    }
  }

  _onBlur() {
    this.setState({hasFocus: false});
    }

  _onFocus() {
    this.setState({hasFocus: true});
    }

  _getULColor(hasFocus) {
    console.error(hasFocus);
    return (hasFocus === true) ? 'pink' : 'violet';
  }

  render() {
    console.error("this.state=");
    console.error(this.state);
    console.error("this.state.hasFocus=");
    console.error(this.state.hasFocus);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="textInput"
            onBlur={ () => this._onBlur() }
            onFocus={ () => this._onFocus() }
            style={styles.instructions}
            underlineColorAndroid={this._getULColor(this.state.hasFocus)}/>
                </ScrollView>
        <TextInput>Some sample text</TextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 28,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    fontSize: 19,
    marginBottom: 5,
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNPlayground', () => RNPlayground);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your code is correct and it should work properly.
[Here is working example](https://rnplay.org/apps/wN9ukQ)

Please, stop downvote this answer. Unfortunately rnplay service isn’t available anymore, as like this example. Or downvote but explain your point.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin. I am using RN with ES2016 and it doesn't work with that. Will post a rnplay sample shortly

Comment: Actually ES6 version should work in the exact way. I guess you have met typical issue with class definition of component, i'm talking about no autobinding of methods - [explanation of differences between methods of creating components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) I've updated my example with es6 syntax, look up on it.

Comment: @Slowyn The links is broken