# How to set 3 different actions for one TextInput field react-native with redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

In my TextInput field I called onChange action if text has been changed. It works very fine with redux.

But i need to add more actions:

onFocuse (if text payload === '0', then i need to change TextInput value to '')

onBlur (if text payload === '', then i need to change TextInput value to '0')

I don't have any idea. For example JQuery decision:

```
function addEventOnChange(obj){
jQuery('#'+obj).bind('keyup mouseup change',function(e){
    change(document.getElementById(obj));
});
jQuery('#'+obj).click(
    function(){//focusin
      clears(document.getElementById(obj));
});
jQuery('#'+obj).blur(
    function(){//focusout
      backzero(document.getElementById(obj));
});
function clears(obj) {
    if (obj.value == 0) {
        obj.value = '';
    }
}    
function backzero(obj) {
    if (obj.value == "") {
        obj.value = 0;
    }
}
```

My current action:

```
export const textInputChanged = (text) => {
  return {
    type: TEXTINPUT_CHANGED,
    payload: text
  };
};
```

Current reducer:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  textinput: '1000' 
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TEXTINPUT_CHANGED:
      return { ...state, textinput: action.payload };
  default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Current App:

```
onTextInputChange(text) {
    this.props.TextInputChanged(number(text));
}

render() {
const number = (text) => { // only for numbers input
  if (text.match(',') !== null) {
    text = text.replace(',', '.');
  }
  if (text.match(/[*.*][0-9]*[*.*]/) !== null) {
    if (text.match(/\.$/)) {
      text = text.replace(/\.$/, '');
    } else {
      text = text.replace(/[.]/, '');
    }
  }
  return text.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
};

return (
      <Card>
        <TextInput
          value={this.props.texinput}
          onChangeText={this.onTextInputChange.bind(this)}          
          onFocus={ clears }
          onBlur={ backzero }         
         />
       </Card>
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    textinput: state.form.textinput,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  TextInputChanged
})(App);
```

Decision smells like componentDidMount(), but I don't feel as well

Comment: Your question is kinda unclear, are you asking, when a user clicks your textInput you want it to be an empty string? and When they leave the text area you want a zero to show up?

Comment: Only if textInput value === '0'

Comment: And I would like to change font to bold if onFocuse, and remove bold font if onBlur

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working. Somewhere may be a more elegant solution. You can add TextInput2, TextInput3, etc. by the same principle in this onFocus && onBlur functions. It turned out without eval)

Current App:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
         TextInputColor: '#525050'
    };
  }

    onFocus(input, text) {
      this.setState({
        [`${input}Color`]: '#000000'
      });
      if (text === '0') {      
        this.props[`${input}Changed`]('');
      }
    }

   onBlur(input, text) {
       this.setState({
         [`${input}Color`]: '#525050'
       });
       if (text === '') {      
         this.props[`${input}Changed`]('0');
       }
    }

    onTextInputChange(text) {
        this.props.TextInputChanged(number(text));
    }

    render() {

    const number = (text) => { // only for numbers input };

    return (
      <Card>
        <TextInput
          value={this.props.texinput}
          onChangeText={this.onTextInputChange.bind(this)}          
          onBlur={() => this.onBlur('TextInput', this.props.textinput)}
          onFocus={() => this.onFocus('TextInput',this.props.textinput)}
          style={{ color: this.state.TextInputColor }}   
        />
      </Card>
      const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
          textinput: state.form.textinput,
        };
      };

      export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
        TextInputChanged
      })(App);
```

[Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbPRT.gif)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're looking for. It was also the first result from google. Just an FYI..

[Focus style for TextInput in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native)

Update....

```
<TextInput 
    onBlur={ () => this.onBlur() }
    onFocus={ () => this.onFocus() }
    style={{ height:60, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, color: this.state.color }}  />

onFocus() {
    this.setState({
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    })
  },



 onBlur() {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: '#ededed'
    })
  },
```

I can't write all the code for you... You will need to setup your code.

```
handleChange(e){
//check if text is what you need then call some function
//e === 0 ? this.onBlur (or this.setState({...})) : null
}
```

Comment: It seems that I need to use componentDidMount() . But how?