# Change the color of Button when onFocus input

Tags: react-native

Good Morning , I tried a simple component with react-native that changes the color of my button while onFocus().I can't find how to change the color . Here is my component . Have you any ideas ?

```
       import React, {Component} from 'react';

       import {
       StyleSheet,Text, View, Button,
      } from 'react-native';

     export default class App extends Component {
     render() {
     return (

    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>

      <TextInput

        maxHeight={200}


        style={styles.textInput}

        ref={(r) => {

          this.textInputRef = r;

        }}

        placeholder={'Message'}

        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"

        onFocus={()=>{/*Here i awant to change the color of Button }}

        testID={'input'}

      />

     <Button color="transparent" id="ScanButton"
        onPress={() => this.setState({text: 'Placeholder Text'})}
        title="Scan Barcode"
      />

    </View>
```

)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Initialize your variable

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isFocus: false
        }
    }
```

In your TextInput add two props onFocus() and onBlur()

```
 <TextInput
        maxHeight={200}
        style={styles.textInput}
        ref={(r) => {
          this.textInputRef = r;
        }}
        placeholder={'Message'}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        onBlur={() => this.onBlur()}
        onFocus={() => this.onFocus()}
        testID={'input'}
      />
```

add two methods in your class to change the state

```
 onFocus() {
        this.setState({
            isFocus: true
        })
    }

 onBlur() {
        this.setState({
            isFocus: false
        })
    }
```

and your button style will be like that

```
<Button  
       color={this.state.isFocus ? 'red' : 'green'}
        id="ScanButton"
        onPress={() => this.setState({text: 'Placeholder Text'})}
        title="Scan Barcode"
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 style={{color: this.props.focused ? '#8B327C' :'#3F8B99'}}
```

try something like this

Comment: Hi where should i add this line please ?

Comment: add this ass a style to component you want its color changed

Comment: it doesn't work because the only way to change  the color of a button in react native is to set directly color:' black' without passing by style .

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native

Comment: @Roozbeh thank u it works with your solution i just did it like that :    <Button color={ this.state.focused ?  '#3F8B99' :'transparent'}
            onPress={() => this.setState({text: 'Placeholder Text'})}
            title="Scan Barcode"
          />