# Using setState in onFocus removes the focus

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I found that the convention to changing css of `TextInput` is by changing the component's state using onFocus and onBlur props.

I learned it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native).

However, though successful I had to do some ugly workaround:

1. I moved the state management to my form component instead of putting it in my `TextInput` wrapper
2. I had to implement a hack `componentDidUpdate()` to refocus the `TextInput`, something like this

```
componentDidUpdate() {
     this.props.isActive ? setTimeout(() => this.input.focus(), 100) : null
}
```

Now everything is working as expected, except that the keyboard would flicker upon moving to the next `TextInput` by using `onSubmitEditing` props.

Here's my code snippet related to this case:

in my form component I instantiate the input wrapper component like so within a loop, i.e. `fields.map()`

```
<AuthTextInput
     ref={ref => inputRefs[key] = ref}
     key={key}
     label={label}
     onFocus={() => this.setState({ currentInput: key })}
     isActive={this.state.currentInput === key}
     onSubmitEditing={() => (idx + 1) < fields.length && fields[idx + 1].type !== 'selection' ? inputRefs[fields[idx + 1].key].focus() : this.setState({ currentInput: null })}
     blurOnSubmit={(idx + 1) === fields.length || fields[idx + 1].type === 'selection'}
     returnKeyType={(idx + 1) === fields.length || fields[idx + 1].type === 'selection' ? 'done' : 'next'}
     autoCapitalize={autocaps}
     secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
     placeholder={placeholder}
     keyboardType={keyboard}
     containerStyle={[{ width: orientation() === 'landscape' ? 0.5 * windowWidth() : windowWidth() * 0.7, height: normalize(70), marginVertical: normalize(10) }]}
     leftIcon={<Image style={{ width: normalize(50), height: normalize(50), marginTop: 25 }} source={fieldIcon} />}  
     onChangeText={(text) => this.onChange(key, text)}
     value={this.state[key] ? this.state[key]['value'] : ''}
     error={this.state.error[key]}
/>
```

The content of AuthTextInput is like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

import { isEmpty } from '../utils/validate';
import { windowWidth, fontSize, fontFamily, normalize, color } from '../theme/baseTheme';
import IconWrapper from './IconWrapper';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    },

    inputContainer: {
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
    },

    inputStyle: {
        fontSize: fontSize.regular + 2,
        fontFamily: fontFamily.bold,
        paddingLeft: normalize(15),
        borderBottomWidth: 1
    },

    errorStyle: {
        color: color.red,
        fontSize: fontSize.small - 4,
        fontFamily: fontFamily.bold,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginLeft: normalize(75)
    },
    focusedContainer: {
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: color.light_blue,
        borderRadius: 8
    }
});

class AuthTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            secureText: this.props.secureTextEntry,
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.isActive ? setTimeout(() => this.input.focus(), 100) : null
    }

    focus() {
        this.input.focus();
    }

    render() {
        const { secureTextEntry, value, containerStyle, isActive } = this.props;

        return (
            <Input
                {...this.props}
                ref={ref => this.input = ref}
                disableFullscreenUI={true}
                secureTextEntry={this.state.secureText}
                containerStyle={[styles.container, containerStyle, isActive ? styles.focusedContainer : null]}
                inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                inputStyle={styles.inputStyle}
                rightIcon={
                    secureTextEntry && value !== '' ?
                        this.state.secureText ?
                            <IconWrapper name="visibility" size={20} color={color.light_grey} style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} onPress={() => this.setState({ secureText: false })} />
                            :
                            <IconWrapper name="visibility-off" size={20} color={color.light_grey} style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} onPress={() => this.setState({ secureText: true })} />
                        :
                        null
                }
                errorMessage={!isEmpty(this.props.error) ? this.props.error : null}
                errorStyle={[styles.errorStyle, this.props.errorStyle]}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default AuthTextInput;
```

The problem I found mainly lies in the first snippet, where I wrote `onFocus={() => this.setState({ currentInput: key })}` which re-renders the form component and somehow removing the focus. Hence, the refocusing in `AuthTextInput`'s `componentDidUpdate`.

I thought when my form component re-renders, all the old `AuthTextInput` are getting destroyed, so I tried doing `autoFocus={this.props.isActive}` too in `AuthTextInput`, but it wasn't successful because `componentDidMount` itself was never called, which implies they didn't get destroyed, just updated.

This made me wonder, if it didn't get destroyed and remade, what made the focus went away?
I mean, I did the same thing to set the value by doing this `onChangeText={(text) => this.onChange(key, text)}` and calling `setState` there. and in that case, the component didn't lose focus.

Anyhow, I would love to know if anyone can either:

1. show me what made the focus go away OR
2. using my workaround above to refocus after setting the form state, prevent keyboard from flickering (dismissing and reappearing within a short interval).

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I found that in my TextInput wrapper, when it is updated the FIRST TIME using `setState` from `onFocus` callback, it always calls `onBlur` right away, which is weird and I couldn't find anything that calls onBlur the first time both in mine or the library `react-native-element`'s code.

UPDATE2:

Turns out even when I already disabled onBlur from being called and updating the component once again right after onFocus, the input still loses focus, and I have no idea what's causing it. I checked both the form's and the input's component didupdate and they didn't fire, odd...
So I guess I just have to find out what's stealing the focus when my onFocus updates the input state

FINAL UPDATE:
INTERESTING FIND!!! `isActive ? styles.focusedContainer : null` this is the culprit, for some reason this is triggering `blur()` event. None of the answers below can recreate this because none of them modifies the css styling of this component.
I think this happens because `containerStyleProps` is passed as the parent's `View` component props to the actual `TextInput` component by `react-native-elements`. This causes rerendering at that level causing `TextInput` to rerender too.
But problem persist, how should I go about solving this issue if simply updating my style triggers the TextInput rerendering? Is there any way to tap into the `TextInput`'s `shouldUpdateComponent()` hook?

Thanks again for any opinion posted here that helped me gain this insight

Comment: SetState is not removing focus, otherwise we couldn't enter two characters in a row in a textInput. Maybe there is a problem with the library react-native-elements, did you check issues on github ?

Comment: @hardworker I did and no mention of it, I suspected the same too but no luck :(

Comment: You can't change style without rendering (except for animated values). If you do a change, the component has to re-render to update his values. If you only want to prevent some style to interact, you could create your own component which return a <TextInput ...props /> and with the "right" shouldUpdateComponent hook.

Comment: @hardworker strangely enough, I did that and it still loses focus although that component that returns textInput never got updated. Anyhow, I ended up just doing my original workaround implementation, it seems to only cause keyboard to flicker on emulator and/or lowend devices. Would be nice to be able to not let this happen at all but this is good enough for now i guess

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the skeleton of the problem. In the below example the input does not loses the focus, works as expected.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isFocus: 'no focus'
  }
  
  handleFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ isFocus: 'got focus' })
  }
  
  handleBlur = () => {
      this.setState({ isFocus: 'no focus' })
  }
   
  
  render() {
    return <input onFocus={this.handleFocus} onBlur={this.handleBlur} value={this.state.isFocus} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
input:focus {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: interesting, maybe it has something to do with the fact that my `Input` component is imported from `react-native-elements` then..

Comment: For some reason, when I follow your skeleton for my case, then put console log everywhere I can see this weird pattern showing: `onFocus` --> `componentDidUpdate` --> `onBlur` --> `componentDidUpdate`, which puzzles me since there's nothing in my code or the library that I use that calls for `blur()`

Comment: Strage... My other recommendation to simply use css :focus selector for styling the input. This way you do not have to touch the style prop of input. It might also effect the focus, however it should not be. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, specifically on Android - iOS seems to be unaffected at the time of writing this.

`onBlur` gets called when the `TextInput` or it's ***container*** is rendering differently based on State variables... as you noted, in your case it was the following:

> **isActive ? styles.focusedContainer : null**

To get around this and keep your `setState` in `onFocus` and `onBlur`, and still style your component beautifully based on state, I managed to fix this issue by separating focus styling from the input, and make it styled on a sibling view instead of a parent view or the input view itself:

```
 <View>
   <View style={ isActive ? styles.focused : styles.unfocused } />
   <Input/>  // <-- do not use state to style this.
 </View>
```

This will avoid the onBlur getting called, however, you will obviously need to correctly position the "un/focus styled" **View** behind the **Input** view to line them up.

For this, use styles for `position='absolute', width='100%', height='100%'`

E.g:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     inputView: {
        width='100%',
        height='100%'
     }
     focusView: {
        position: 'absolute',   // <--- this is the key
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
}
```