# React native render component based on TextInput onfocus

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display something in my react component when user clicks into a text input (something similar to Instagram's search, where if you click on their input field, a search component suggestion shows up.

```
const SearchScreen = props => {

  const renderSearch = () => {
    return (
      <>
       // need to display the search suggestion
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)}
        value={searchText}
        onFocus={() => renderSearch()} // based on focus, then render component
      />
      <View>
        // how do I render here?
        // this will render on load, but need to render onFocus
        {renderSearch}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can apply a similar pattern than https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091564/1839692. For instance you can use an `const [searchFocus, setSearchFocus] = useState(false)` to display (or not) your component and set this value accordingly in your `onFocus`, `onBlur` events.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Focus style for TextInput in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native)

Comment: Ah got it! yeah it did, thank you! do you want to answer the question? perhaps write a snippet so I can approve?

Comment: Done. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a similar pattern than stackoverflow.com/a/34091564/1839692.

For instance you can try something like :

```
const SearchScreen = props => {
  const [searchFocus, setSearchFocus] = useState(false)

  const renderSearch = () => {
    return (
      <>
       // need to display the search suggestion
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={text => handleChange(text)}
        value={searchText}
        onFocus={() => setSearchFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setSearchFocus(false)}
      />
      { searchFocus 
        ? <View>
            {renderSearch}
          </View> 
        : <View>
            // Add here the code to display when not searching
          </View>
      }

    </>
  );
};
```