# toggle view when clicked on TextInput in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a `TextInput`, in that I have a view which ,makes the text come in between of the top border of `TextInput` as shown in image below.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from "react-native";

const AddAddressScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.TextInputcontainer}>
            <View style={styles.TextInputlabelContainer}> // this should toggle when clicked in and out of TextInput
                <Text style={styles.labelText}>Search</Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput style={styles.textSearchInput} selectionColor={"black"} placeholder="Search" />
        </View>
    );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    TextInputcontainer: {
        height: 50, width: 200, marginTop: 50,
    },
    TextInputlabelContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        top: -10.5, left: 20, zIndex: 1,
    },
    labelText: {
        color: "black",
    },
    textSearchInput: {
        flex: 1,
        borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#9E9E9E",
        color: "#9E9E9E"
    },
});
export default AddAddressScreen;
```

There is view with `styles.TextInputlabelContainer`, I have also written comment at that place.
I want that `view` to only come when user clicks on the `TextInput`. I am still in the learning phase of react native so I am not able to think on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try With onFocus & onBlur Method in TextInput:

You can also get Reference From Below Link
[Focus style for TextInput in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1):

Use `onFocus` and `onBlur` props to set the visibility state and use that to show or hide the `TextInput` label.

**Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/great-croissant)**

[image]

**Solution:**

```js
import React, { useState, } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const AddAddressScreen = () => {
  const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.TextInputcontainer}>
      {showLabel && (
        <View style={styles.TextInputlabelContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.labelText}>Search</Text>
        </View>
      )}
      <TextInput
        ref={btnRef}
        style={styles.textSearchInput}
        selectionColor={'black'}
        placeholder="Search"
        onFocus={() => {
          setShowLabel(true);
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
          setShowLabel(false);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  TextInputcontainer: {
    height: 50,
    width: 200,
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  TextInputlabelContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    top: -10.5,
    left: 20,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  labelText: {
    color: 'black',
  },
  textSearchInput: {
    flex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#9E9E9E',
    color: '#9E9E9E',
  },
});
export default AddAddressScreen;
```