# zIndex issue in android for react-native-autocomplete-input

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, z-index

I am running into an issue in my react native app that uses `react-native-autocomplete-input`. The issue only occurs in android, which, according to the `react-native-autocomplete-input` has known issues:

> Android does not support overflows (#20), for that reason it is
> necessary to wrap the autocomplete into a absolute positioned view on
> Android. This will allow the suggestion list to overlap other views
> inside your component.

I am wrapping the autocomplete in an absolute positioned view, as suggested. And this solves some issues.

However, what's still happening is, if I have two autocomplete fields - one appearing higher on the screen than another, when the first field has the suggestion box open up, overlaying on the screen, if a user clicks on a suggestion that happens to line up with the input field immediately "under" that suggestion, the cursor suddenly jumps to that input field. So this is obviously some kind of `zIndex` issue.

The thing is, I have tried setting various `zIndex` values, so that the text field and its container has a lower value than the autocomplete suggestion box, but this is not preventing the behavior I described above from happening.

I have read about `elevation` in android. Is this something I can use, and if so, how? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the relevant android styling for `react-native-autcomplete-input`. And `list` refers to the autocomplete suggestions box that overlays on the screen:

```
const androidStyles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    marginBottom: 0,
    zIndex: -1,
    left: 40,
  },
  input: {
    zIndex: -1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    maxHeight: 200,
    fontSize: 15,
    borderWidth: 0,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  list: {
    ...border,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    margin: 10,
    marginTop: 1,
    zIndex: 99999,
    borderRadius: 15,
    width: '65%',
    zIndex: 99999,
  },
  listContainer: {
    zIndex: 99999,
  }
};
```

Comment: You should reset an higher z-index on :focus, so it is only avalaible at that time and it will be surely laying on top ;)  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087459/focus-style-for-textinput-in-react-native it should help

Comment: To be clear, I want the higher zIndex applied to the overlaying list of suggestions, not on the underlying input field.